# How to retrieve returned information from API

Tags: reactjs, react-native, google-api

I have a function in React Native which calls the Google Routes API. I got the expected response when debugging inside the function but when I try to store the information returned by the API inside a variable, variable shows undefined. How can I fix this?

Code:

```
async function computeDuration(currentLocation, targetLocation, travelMode, routingPreference){
    const apiKey = config.GOOG_ROUTES_API_KEY; 
    const requestBody = {
      origin: {
        location: {
          latLng: {
            latitude: currentLocation.coords.latitude,
            longitude: currentLocation.coords.longitude,
          },
        },
      },
      destination: {
        location: {
          latLng: {
            latitude: targetLocation.latitude,
            longitude: targetLocation.longitude,
          },
        },
      },
      travelMode: travelMode,
      routingPreference: routingPreference, 
      computeAlternativeRoutes: false,
      routeModifiers: {
        avoidTolls: false,
        avoidHighways: false,
        avoidFerries: false,
      },
      languageCode: "en-US",
      units: "METRIC",
    };

    fetch("https://routes.googleapis.com/directions/v2:computeRoutes", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "X-Goog-Api-Key": apiKey,
        "X-Goog-FieldMask":
          "routes.duration,routes.distanceMeters",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(requestBody),
    })
      .then((response) => {
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error("Network response was not ok");
        }
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        // Handle the response data here
        console.log(data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error:", error);
      });
  }

const getAPIData = () => {
    data = computeDuration(location, { latitude, longitude }, "DRIVE", "TRAFFIC_AWARE")
    console.log("This is api data:", data)
  };
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see, you use the async function and when we call the async function you must await the result of that function.

Fix this:

wrong way >

```
 const getAPIData = () => {
    data = computeDuration(location, { latitude, longitude }, "DRIVE", "TRAFFIC_AWARE")
    console.log("This is api data:", data)
  };
```

correct way >

```
const getAPIData = async () => {
    data = await computeDuration(location, { latitude, longitude }, "DRIVE", "TRAFFIC_AWARE")
    console.log("This is api data:", data)
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

The response from computeDuration function should be returned and await should be used to get it from computeDuration function.

```
const getAPIData = async () => {
    data = await computeDuration(location, { latitude, longitude }, "DRIVE", "TRAFFIC_AWARE")
    console.log("This is api data:", data)
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution. The problem is also in how data is returned from my function.

Fixed code:

```
async function computeDuration(currentLocation, targetLocation, travelMode, routingPreference) {
    const apiKey = config.GOOG_ROUTES_API_KEY;
    const requestBody = {
      origin: {
        location: {
          latLng: {
            latitude: currentLocation.coords.latitude,
            longitude: currentLocation.coords.longitude,
          },
        },
      },
      destination: {
        location: {
          latLng: {
            latitude: targetLocation.latitude,
            longitude: targetLocation.longitude,
          },
        },
      },
      travelMode: travelMode,
      routingPreference: routingPreference,
      computeAlternativeRoutes: false,
      routeModifiers: {
        avoidTolls: false,
        avoidHighways: false,
        avoidFerries: false,
      },
      languageCode: "en-US",
      units: "METRIC",
    };
  
    try {
      const response = await fetch("https://routes.googleapis.com/directions/v2:computeRoutes", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "X-Goog-Api-Key": apiKey,
          "X-Goog-FieldMask": "routes.duration,routes.distanceMeters",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(requestBody),
      });
  
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error("Network response was not ok");
      }
  
      const data = await response.json();
      return data; // Return the data
  
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error:", error);
      throw error; // Rethrow the error for the caller to handle
    }
  }

const getAPIData = async () => {
    data = await computeDuration(location, { latitude, longitude }, "DRIVE", "TRAFFIC_AWARE")
    console.log("This is api data:", data)
  };
```